# How to run svn list when using psvn in emacs?

Tags: svn, emacs

I'm trying to do two things:

How can I do the equivalent of

```
$ svn list svn+ssh://user@hostname/path/to/repo
```

and after that how does one initially check out a file in that same repo called filename.ext

```
$ svn co svn+ssh://user@hostname/path/to/repo/filename.ext
```

when using psvn from within emacs?  Once something has already been checked out - no problem.. I'm good with psvn and know what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK there's no way to do that directly with psvn, but you can easily run those commands from Emacs using either <kbd>M-!</kbd> or <kbd>M-x compile</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

`M-x svn-status-ls` does the job.